# Data table cap and floor assigning new variables

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of variables I want to cap and floor but I want to save them with a different name to not overwrite the variables.
Example with mtcars that yields an error:

```
# Variables to cap and floor
mtcars_vars <- c("wt","qsec","mpg")

# Function to cap and floor 
cap_floor <- function(x,pct_floor = 0.05, pct_cap = 0.95){
  quantiles <- quantile( x, c( pct_floor, pct_cap ),na.rm = TRUE)
  x[ x < quantiles[1] ] <- quantiles[1]
  x[ x > quantiles[2] ] <- quantiles[2]
  x
}

mtcars[,paste0(mtcars_vars,"_cap_fl") := lapply(mtcars_vars, cap_floor)]
```

This yields a Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator although the function seems to work fine with individual columns.

```
cap_floor(mtcars$qsec)
cap_floor(mtcars$wt)
cap_floor(mtcars$mpg)
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially `lapply()`'ing over a character vector. You could use `.SDcols`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)
DTmtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
DTmtcars[,paste0(mtcars_vars,"_cap_fl") := lapply(.SD, cap_floor), .SDcols = mtcars_vars]

> head(DTmtcars)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb wt_cap_fl qsec_cap_fl mpg_cap_fl
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     2.620     16.4600       21.0
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     2.875     17.0200       21.0
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     2.320     18.6100       22.8
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     3.215     19.4400       21.4
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     3.440     17.0200       18.7
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     3.460     20.1045       18.1
```